# Make height of input and div equal to their parent

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've got the following code:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 25px;
}
.myInput {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-right: none;
}
.myInputAddon {
  width: 25px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input class="myInput">
  <div class="myInputAddon" type="number"></div>
</div>
```

I thought, when I give a hardcoded height to my wrapper div (in the example 25px) and then `height: 100%;` to his child-elements, they would flex correctly and have the same height.

But in my snippet, my input is higher than my div.

If I remove the height from the wrapper div and give the input a height 23px and to the child-div 25px, it works. But I would like to set it a little bit dynamically.

It should look like this:

[image]

How can I do this?

Thanks and cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is **default padding** of input element so you can just add [`box-sizing: border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) and keep padding inside height of element.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 25px;
}
.wrapper * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.myInput {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-right: none;
}
.myInputAddon {
  width: 25px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input class="myInput">

  <div class="myInputAddon" type="number"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `input` element has default styling from the browser:

[image]

Make the following adjustments:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 25px;
}
.myInput {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-right: none;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* NEW; padding and border now absorbed into height:100% */
}
.myInputAddon {
  width: 25px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid green;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* NEW */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input class="myInput">
  <div class="myInputAddon" type="number"></div>
</div>
```